# How to create Executable of iPad

Tags: ipad, executable

I am making my first ever application in iPad.

I have created all my development and distribution certificates from iOs Dev Portal and added them onto the organizer and keychain.

Now i want to know that how to create an executable of my application and send that to the client for testing.

Please tell me what is the best solution for that and how to install that executable on my iPad

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is what Apple calls "Ad Hoc Distribution"; if you don't like Apple's own documentation then [a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=ad+hoc+distribution) will reveal plenty of information on how to do it.

You don't need physical access to the testing device, but you do need the device's unique identifier (UDID).

You might want to consider a service like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) which automates much of the work required install an ad hoc build directly onto an iOS device, over the network (rather than through iTunes sync).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have to add the client's device as a development device and plug it into your development Mac in order to test it. It might be different with an Enterprise development account, I don't know. With a personal account the only way to distribute your App is via App Store.

I would like to know this myself so please update the question if you find out please.